# Can the total supply of a token on Ethereum be increase?

Tags: tokens

I've noticed on coinmarketcap some ethereum tokens have a "max supply" value while others don't and from what I understand, correct me if I'm wrong, Tether is an ethereum token they're able to increase their total supply.

So my question, are companies able to increase their token supply whenever they want or is it a fixed number set at the ICO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question, are companies able to increase their token supply
>   whenever they want or is it a fixed number set at the ICO?

**tl;dr** There is no generic answer to your question. It all depends on how the particular company decided to design their crowdsale.

There are different scenarios where a crowdsale can have either some fixed total supply or it will have 0 total supply at the start of crowdsale and then during crowdsale the total supply will get increased by minting new tokens. And of course it is still possible for companies to design their smart contract in the way that they can increase amount of tokens or mint after crowdsale.

Answer (score 1):

A token on Ethereum is just a smart contract. The code in the smart contract can do anything. It could use a fixed supply, or it could allow the supply to change, or it could make everyone's balance zero on Tuesdays.